# double pointer and memory allocation

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, struct

I have a structure that uses double pointers to make a matrix:

```
typedef struct
{
       int rows, cols;
       int** element;
}Matrix;
```

I am writing a function that initializes a matrix by dynamically allocating memory to this structures. This is the code I have written but I get a segmentation fault when I try to access a->rows,cols, or element in another function or in main.

```
void matrixInit (Matrix* ma, int m, int n)
 {   int i;
     ma=(Matrix*)malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
     ma->rows=m;
     ma->cols=n;

     ma->element=malloc(m*sizeof(int*));
     for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        {ma->element[i]=malloc(n*sizeof(int));
        }

 }
```

Any help please?

Comment: Where is the declaration of `ma`? Why do you have two arguments named `m`?

Comment: it is. sorry. it was originally named matx and I changed it to m to make it simpler.

Comment: You should show an example of the access that causes the segmentation fault.

Comment: should be correct now

Comment: You'll want to pass in a pointer-to-pointer-to-Matrix so that the `malloc`ed pointer is available to the caller. Also check if `malloc` doesn't return `NULL` and don't cast the first `malloc` (the one that allocates `ma`) either.

Comment: for example, in main I call matrixInit(matx,3,4);when i try to call matx->rows it will seg fault

Comment: Your classmate had the same problem:  [20412318](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20412318)

Comment: @ woolstar I highly doubt it.My assignment was due a couple of days ago. But thanks for linking the question. I didn't come upon it when I looked on the website a couple of days ago.

Comment: @user3075598 given that he was required to pass in Matrix by pointer, couldn't return a pointer, or pass in a `** Matrix`, either its a classmate, or some other school is teaching out of the same exact lesson plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call a function like this, you pass it a value of a pointer to a matrix. When you actually create the matrix in the function, you only assign it locally.

You should pass a pointer to the variable where the matrix pointer is to be stored, i.e. `Matrix **ma`.

```
void matrixInit (Matrix **ma_ptr, int m, int n)
{
    int i;
    *ma_ptr = (Matrix*)malloc(sizeof(Matrix));

    Matrix *ma = *ma_ptr;
    ma->rows=m;
    ma->cols=n;
    ma->element=malloc(m*sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        ma->element[i]=malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    }
}
```

and then call this method with an address ofthe variable where you want your matrix to be stored.

```
Matrix *m;
matrixInit(&m, 4, 4);
```

Another way is to allocate memory for the matrix itself **outside** of the function.
Your function will stay exactly the way you wrote it, except you remove the allocation

```
ma = (Matrix*)malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
```

Then you will pass it a pointer to a Matrix, but you have to ensure it points to a Matrix struct. You can do this by declaring a `Matrix*` variable and calling malloc() outside of the function (and thus allocating it on the heap), or declare a variable of type `Matrix` (and have it allocated on the stack).

```
Matrix ma;
matrixInit(&ma, 4, 4);
```

Comment: Your code works well but I am doing this for an assignment and we were specifically told to have a function with the input being a matrix pointer, not a double pointer.

Comment: You can achieve this by removing the allocation from the function, declaring `Matrix m` and calling the function with `&m` instead.

Answer (score 1):

In C, every function argument is passed by value. This means that when you give an argument to a function, a copy of the value (not the value itself) is passed as the argument in the function. This includes pointers - you can change whatever the pointer refers to and have no problems, but if you set the pointer to point to something else in the function, the change only applies to a local copy of the pointer.

```
ma=(Matrix*)malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
```

Here, instead of making the input pointer point to a newly allocated memory for a `Matrix` struct, you are in fact overwriting a local pointer `ma` with a new one without doing anything to the input pointer. This causes the issue. To fix this, you could return a pointer to `ma` instead.

Comment: thank you! I now understand why it would seg fault. But is there any way of accessing the matrix created in the function without changing the function parameters?

Comment: If you make it return a pointer to the newly allocated `Matrix` you don't need to change the parameters (although the first argument, which is essentially an output parameter, is of no use if you return stuff too). Alternatively, you can pass `Matrix**` as the first argument and change the `Matrix*` it refers to inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to pass in a pointer-to-pointer-to-Matrix so that the malloced pointer is available to the caller. Like this:

```
void matrixInit (Matrix ** ma, int m, int n)
{
    *ma = malloc(sizeof **ma); // sizeof **ma == sizeof(Matrix)
```

Then call it with this:

```
Matrix * matx;
matrixInit(&matx, 3, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't return the matrix it creates. Do this instead.

```
Matrix * matrixInit (int m, int n)
 {
   Matrix* ma;
   int i;
     ma=(Matrix*)malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
     ...
     return ma;
 }
```

... and then use it thus

```
Matrix * myMatrix;
myMatrix = matrixInit(8,8);  // chessboard
```